# Template member function in regular class in template class does not compile with GCC but does with VC++

Tags: c++

I am porting a C++ template library from VC++ to GCC.

The example below compiles fine with VS2005

```
#include <iostream>

template<class T>
struct A{
  struct B{
    template<int n>
    T foo() const{
      return static_cast<T>(n)/10;
    }
  };

  T bar() const{
    B b;
    return b.foo<2>();
  }
};

int main(){
  A<float> a;
  std::cout << a.bar() << std::endl;
  return 0;
}
```

but with GCC 4.4.1 I get the following errors

```
g++ ttest.cpp -o ttest
ttest.cpp: In member function ‘T A<T>::bar() const’:
ttest.cpp:14: error: expected primary-expression before ‘)’ token
ttest.cpp: In member function ‘T A<T>::bar() const [with T = float]’:
ttest.cpp:20:   instantiated from here
ttest.cpp:14: error: invalid operands of types ‘<unresolved overloaded function type>’ and ‘int’ to binary ‘operator<’
make: *** [ttest] Error 1
```

Could someone please explain to me what is wrong.

Is this compliant with the standard or not?

Answer (score 6):

You are missing a keyword, when invoking `foo` - which is a function template, you have to explicitly tell GCC it's a template, with the following horrible syntax (don't ask me why they thought it was sensible).

```
return b.template foo<2>();
```

EDIT: I'm not a language lawyer, so can't tell you whether it's standards compliant or not, I'm sure one of the many on this site can! ;)

Comment: Thank you very much! That is one use of the template keyword I was not aware of.

Comment: +1. Nim, its correct, and is required by the language specification.

Comment: The standard says it's required, because the C++ grammar is ambiguous without knowing what is a type and what is a template. E.g `return b.foo<2>(5)` would have been ambiguous (`(b.foo < 2) > 5)` vs. `b.template foo<2>(5)`). Visual C++ works this around, probably by postponing the syntax analysis until instantiation of the template. Gcc does not because it would mean restructuring the compiler and because it's authors like to follow the specification to the letter.